# Authlogic ignoring password parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

Authlogic seems to be ignoring the password parameter when creating a new user. Here's my users_controller class:

```
class Api::V1::UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.json  { render :json => @user, :status => :created}
      else
        format.json  { render :json => @user.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
  end

end
```

And my user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_authentic do |c|
      c.require_password_confirmation = false
    end
end
```

When I send a POST request to /api/v1/users/ with a username, email and password parameter, authlogic says that the password cannot be blank even though it isn't. Here's whats printed out by rails:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/users/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-06-22 00:03:30 -0400
Processing by Api::V1::UsersController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"someemail@website.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"myUser", "user"=>{"username"=>"myUser", "email"=>"someemail@website.com"}}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('someemail@website.com') LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('myUser') LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."persistence_token" = '7b72bab3627914d33e83e4efe1c5a9dab190750efb227698c8b5b6be7a7ccf118160d8e12623078543e0f4e5f31eb30828799cb0d97fb2af195daee894c79902' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 33ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
```

I'm using the latest authlogic and Ruby 2/Rails 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at an excerpt from Rails log:

```
{"email"=>"someemail@website.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"myUser", "user"=>{"username"=>"myUser", "email"=>"someemail@website.com"}}
```

It looks like you send slightly wrong parameters. To be recognized by Authlogic, `password` parameter should go under `user` key in parameters hash. I.e. that line from Rails log should look like this (pay attention to the end of string):

```
{"email"=>"someemail@website.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"myUser", "user"=>{"username"=>"myUser", "email"=>"someemail@website.com", "password" => "[FILTERED]"}}
```

To fix it, you can do a hack like this:

```
private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email).merge(:password => :password)
end
```

Alternatively, you can adjust the parameters sent from the client side (for example, using `user[password]` parameter's name instead of just `password` when sending `HTTP POST` request).

Answer (score 0):

try this out:-

```
acts_as_authentic do |config|
  config.check_passwords_against_database = false
  config.validate_password_field = false
  config.crypted_password_field = false
end
```

Comment: That allows the user to be created, but it does so without a password. I need my users to have a password.